# Call of Duty: Black Ops Co-op

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops

Does COD:BO (on XBOX 360) have an offline co-operative mode for the campaign like Gears of War, Halo 3 or Borderlands do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no co-op campaign. You can only co-op in online multi-player and Zombie mode.

Answer (score 0):

However, the online multiplayer has "combat training" that is allows you to set up team death match and deathmatch games. This mode has a separate levelling system that mirrors the normal pvp stuff and does allow your friends to join a match against or with the bots that populate the training mode. Lots of fun to get kill streaks and practice with the glory that is a gunship or unleash the alsatians on unsuspecting bots.